# Xcode how to add swipe down Action in UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I discovered a UITableView function in an app that I would like to implement into my app. I just really don't know how to do it. i have already looked through the whole internet. The function I want to implement is a SWipe Down action. So if a user swipes his finger from top to bottom for a long time, the function is carried out.[That is what it Looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iVeS.png)

Does somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are looking for `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`

[UISwipeGestureRecognizer docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer)

You attach a gesture recognizer to a view and when the user completes that gesture, the recognizer can perform an action.

Comment: yes that can be but I don't know how I then implement that so that the function is only called when you have arrived at the tableview and then swipe up